# listening for window resize using only document.ready

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider, window-resize

I am trying to create a responsive jquery slider plugin and need help calling the function.

I have noticed other slider plugins work on window resize even though they are only called as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".element").customFunction();
});
```

Is it possible withing the plugin after it is loaded initially to consistently check for window resizing even though the plugin is only loaded once on document.ready

Hopefully that makes sense , any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

David

Comment: Can you describe more ? Plugin or sample fiddle might work for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a resize listener to the window inside your plugin.

```
....
$(window).resize(function(){
   //your logic
});
....
```